# Is there a web site where you can surf on another web site (in a frame, for instance)

Tags: browser, website, lan

I wonder if it exists a web site that offers the possibility to surf on another web site (in a frame or something like that). The fact is that when you're hosting a web site, you are not always in a configuration to see the website as the "outside" people see it. I think there are some NAT or router issues that make you believe that everything is alright, but that's only just the case from a LAN point of view (and vice versa : the website seems to be broken because you're on the same LAN as the web server). The service would be like you're making a Terminal Service connexion to a host outside your LAN and surf from there on the webserver...

Comment: Sorry, questions about websites are [off-topic](http://superuser.com/faq) on Super User. Voting to close. The [web apps site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications) will be a better place to ask this (public beta starting tonight)

Comment: What we did on SF before SU opened was to tag questions like this with a [belongs-on-superuser] tag, so people could still get their info, and the questions could be moved to the new site once it was open...

Comment: @kara - unfortunately, this leads to people using these tags even when it's possible to migrate, just because they don't have the reputation to vote to close. It took long enough to get rid of that on SO, from what I understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most anonymizers allow you to surf web sites through them.

There's http://www.hidemyass.com/, http://anonymouse.org/ and a ton of others.

Bear in mind that this is a third party and you might leak sensitive data (like site admin passwords) that's being sent through it.

I think you could also use tor for the purpose of "seeing your own site from outside", the sensitive data concern applies there as well.